# Web API Object From Body is Null in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web forms app where I'm trying to call ValidateRegistration1 method fro web api controller. It's doing fine in Firefox and Chrome but the object is null when I use IE. Content type and others seem almost the same. I couldn't find the problem.

Firefox POST in fiddler:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:5555/api/accounts/registervalidate1', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Connection: keep-alive
  Pragma: no-cache
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Accept-Encoding: deflate
  Accept-Language: en-US
  Accept-Language: en; q=0.5
  Cookie: __AntiXsrfToken=0871e412cceb47faa968c5563d19f8e1; ASP.NET_SessionId=glwlyn2mdihne0ev4uhc5fnv
  Host: localhost:5555
  Referer: http://localhost:5555/
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
  User-Agent: (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0)
  User-Agent: Gecko/20100101
  User-Agent: Firefox/25.0
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  Content-Length: 207
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
}}
```

IE POST in fiddler:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:5555/api/accounts/registervalidate1', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Pragma: no-cache
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Accept-Encoding: deflate
  Accept-Language: en-US
  Accept-Language: en; q=0.7
  Accept-Language: tr; q=0.3
  Cookie: __AntiXsrfToken=4772bed0c8e243f4a7893794ed176f47
  Host: localhost:5555
  Referer: http://localhost:5555/
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
  User-Agent: (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)
  User-Agent: like
  User-Agent: Gecko
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  Content-Length: 0
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
}}
```

web api method

```
    [Route("registervalidate1")]
    //[ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage ValidateRegistrationStep1(HttpRequestMessage request, 
        [FromBody]AccountRegisterModel a)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();

        bool isEmailFree = _accountService.EmailInUse(a.LoginEmail);
        if (isEmailFree)
            errors.Add("jj.");

        if (errors.Count == 0)
            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        else
            response = request.CreateResponse<string[]>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors.ToArray());
        return response;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. The fix for me was to manually add the content type of "application/json" (`contentType: 'application/json'`) to my jQuery ajax call. I'm sure you've found a solution to this by now but I'm posting this for others out there with the same problem.